# What are the methods for detecting anagenetic versus cladogenetic change?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, phylogenetics, molecular-evolution

I'm new to the study of phylogenetics and am wondering if there are ways of identifying evolutionary changes that associate with cladogenetic events versus those that arise via anagenesis.

Comment: This is thorny, but also depends on exactly what you're asking. What sort of evolutionary changes/traits are you interested in?

Comment: Additionally, are you interested in studying anagenetic change within the context of phylogenetic inference, or within the context of trait evolution along an inferred phylogeny?

Comment: I'm interested in the evolution of a multistate trait along an inferred phylogeny. I want to know if there is any reason to think that the trait changes are associated with cladogenesis (i.e., took place around the time of cladogenetic events).

Comment: If you're interesting in connecting traits to rates of speciation and extinction, then [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/65/4/583/1753616) might offer some leads. I'm not sure about how one would go about it for a particular node or set of nodes, but perhaps methods based on [stochastic mapping](https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/52/2/131/1634311) could be helpful?

Comment: Thank you! That article was very helpful.